# custom email template is showing header and footer from Luma theme?

Tags: magento2, layout, email-templates

I have created custom email template in my custom module for contact form. while submitting form email should have to trigger to **admin** and end **user** and email also triggering as per requirement but it is taking header and footer from **luma theme**.
But we need header and footer from our custom theme.
Please, below attachment for more clarity:
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I am also facing issue

Comment: Have you resolved this issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used below code to send mail to customer

```
$templateOptions = array(
            'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
        );

 $from = array('email' => $seller_email, 'name' => $post['name']);

            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $to = array($goshop_email);
            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($template_id)
                    ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                    ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                    ->setFrom($from)
                    ->addTo($to)
                    ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
```

**for**

```
'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
```

**use**

```
'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
```

**Where**

```
$this->storeManager is alise of Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
```

Comment: perfect... I was doing same mistake. Your have saved my time.